# How to avoid windows "Don't Answer" message on a program

Tags: c++, windows, qt

When making a program with Qt, we can have long recursive process,

If so, after a while, windows show the "Dont answer" message next to the window title.

This message could lead the user to think the program don't work which is not true.

How can I do to avoid this message in Qt?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to remain responsive to the system and user input, put a long running task into its own thread. You might also want to provide feedback to the user, like a progress bar, so he sees the program is still doing some job he requested.

See also [Threading Basics](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/thread-basics.html) for an introduction on using threads with Qt and [Threading and Concurrent Programming Examples](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/examples-threadandconcurrent.html) for some examples.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I used QtConcurrent::run(), which is perfect for what I wanted.

Answer (score 3):

If your process takes a long time because of loops (or recursive functions), you can call QCoreApplication::processEvents() in your loop to ask your application to treat events.

If you have only one instruction that take a long time (such as copy a large file), you may use QThread or QtConcurrent.

Answer (score 2):

While Olaf's answer is good, a simpler approach would be to sprinkle [QCoreApplication::processEvents()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents) in your code.

From the docs:

> Processes all pending events for the calling thread according to the
>   specified flags until there are no more events to process. You can
>   call this function occasionally when your program is busy performing a
>   long operation (e.g. copying a file).